# How to prevent the index.html from being cached

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, browser-cache

I have Spring-boot application with React frontend. All is bundled together to a single *.jar file with gradle.

My production bundle of my React frontend is located in **src/main/resources/static** folder. In production *.jar file is located in **BOOT-INF/classes/static** folder. In this static folder is located **index.html** and another **static** folder with **media, js and css** folders.

The problem I am trying to solve is, that browsers are caching the main index.html file. in this index, all hashes of bundles are correct, but the index itself is not always requested from the server, but from the browser cache.

I've tried the following things to prevent caching:

```
@Configuration
public class BaseConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/index.html")
            .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS).mustRevalidate())
            .setCacheControl(CacheControl.noCache())
            .setCacheControl(CacheControl.noStore())
            .resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
    }
}
```

and this in one of my controllers:

```
@GetMapping("/index.html")
public void getIndex(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate");
}
```

But without any luck. This is my response headers from the server:
[image]

I assume that every time I press the f5 key (refresh the page), a new index.html with a new hashes should be loaded from the server. But that is not happening. Even when the application is not running on the server, the old index.html still returns from the browser, in which the whole React app is started.

How can I force the browsers to load index.html every time when I press the f5, or when I open the new browser tab?

Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my mistake, the problem was a registered React ServiceWorker, not the bad Spring-boot configuration.

Comment: Hey. Can you elaborate on that? I have a similar tech stack and problem: after deployment to PROD some users cannot load JS because index.html has old bundles.

Comment: I have the same issue. Not using a service worker on the client side.

Comment: Hi @rj3005 do you able to solve the issue ?